# Syncing or version controlling virtualbox VMs

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, rsync, unison

I recently set up a handy Arch Linux development environment inside a VirtualBox VM on Windows 7.

How can I keep this development environment in version control so I can simply "check out" the environment itself on a new computer?

What VirtualBox files do I need in version control besides the .vdi file?

How can I use rsync to keep two VMs in sync?

I'm not interested in backing up the VM once by hand, exporting an "appliance," or fiddling with a GUI to achieve this; the syncing/versioning process must be completely scriptable.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [git-annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/) & [bup](https://github.com/apenwarr/bup).

*bup* does the rsync thing.

*git-annex* relaxes the git 'duplicate the lot' requirement; so you could have your entire VirtualBox data distributed across multiple storage media, and have configurable per-file data redundancy.

Both are scriptable. No more snapshot woes.

[This link](http://craig0990.wordpress.com/2011/10/11/git-git-annex-and-bup/) has further details about git, git-annex and bup.

> What VirtualBox files do I need in version control besides the .vdi
>   file?

I am using a *pre-oracle version of VirtualBox. For my antique version: in addition to the vdi files, I also maintain all the vbox config files; so that's all the xml under the `/machine/` directory & also the main `VirtualBox.xml` file.

Comment: nb: due to my status &the ongoing need for tellytubbyland policing, i was unable to post [this third link@ a random blog with some further details](http://craig0990.wordpress.com/2011/10/11/git-git-annex-and-bup/)